# R package recommenderlab: getRatings for association rules

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I am testing a binary recommendation systems I created with the recommenderlab package in R. I tested the UBCF, Association Rules and Popular algorithms. When I use the method getRatings(recom) for Association Rules, I got a NULL result (the method getRatings works perfectly for UBCF).

Below you can find the complete code. More generally, how can I get the confidences of my predictions for association rules also?

```
    library("recommenderlab")
    training_data <- read.csv("training.csv",";",header=TRUE)
    mtx <- as(training_data,"binaryRatingMatrix")
    mtx = mtx[rowCounts(mtx) > 5,]
    test_index <- evaluationScheme(mtx, method="split", train=0.9, given=1)

    # creation of recommender model based on ubcf, popular, rda
    Rec.ubcf <- Recommender(getData(test_index, "train"), "UBCF")
    Rec.popular <- Recommender(getData(test_index, "train"), "POPULAR")
    Rec.rda <- Recommender(getData(test_index, "train"), "AR", param = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.2, maxlen = 2))

    # making predictions on the test data set
    p.ubcf <- predict(Rec.ubcf, getData(test_index, "known"), type="topNList", n=5)
    p.popular <- predict(Rec.popular, getData(test_index, "known"), type="topNList", n=5)
    p.rda <- predict(Rec.rda, getData(test_index, "known"), type="topNList", n=5)

    as(p.rda,"list")
    getRatings(p.rda)
    > NULL
```

Comment: It would always be good to share sample input and expected output data, which be helpful for others to investigate

Comment: Try changing the values of support, confidence and maxlen to ensure that rules are being generated. Else try `getRatingMatrix()`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Rules are generated because I get back my recommendation: > as(p.rda,"list") $U4 [1] "I3" "I2". The problem here is that seems to be missing the ratings. By using the method getRatingMatrix(p.rda) I get the following error:  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘getRatingMatrix’ for signature ‘"topNList"’